# Approximating a bivariate distribution with another distribution, which method to use?

Tags: distributions, distance, approximation, multivariate-distribution

Let $X \sim F(;\theta)$ and $Y \sim G(;\eta)$ be two independent continuous random variables. The greek symbols represent the parameters of those distributions. I can easily sample from these distributions.

Let $(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}) \sim H(;\kappa)$. These variables are not independent. In fact, I know the conditional distribution of $\tilde{X}\mid \tilde{Y}$ and the marginal distribution of $\tilde{Y}$.

For specific parameter values $\theta$ and $\eta$, how can I find the parameters $\kappa$ that better approximate (in any sense computationally feasible, KL divergence, TV, etcetera) the distribution of $(X,Y)$?

Comment: It might help to define your symbols, such as $\tilde{X}$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.